# Login con Google en Angular (No aparece el popup para loguearse)

Tags: angular, login, google-api

Utilizo la librería `@abacritt/angularx-social-login`.

Cuando presiono un botón en mi frontend, llamo a una función.

```
 async login() {
    this.store.dispatch(fromUser.login());
 }
```

La acción que corre este effect.
La parte mas importante es la que está en el medio (separada por espacios), del return.

```
    getUserLoginEffect$ = createEffect(() => {
        .............
                
    
                return this.authSvc.loginWithGoogle().then( (auth2:any) => {
                    console.log(auth2)
                    //const user:UserGoogle = auth2.currentUser.Pb.Cv;
                    const user:any=auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile()
                    console.log("Este es el user", user)
    
    ..........
   }
```

Y esta es la función del service.

```
async loginWithGoogle() {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()?.disconnect(); //Probé intentando desconectarme antes de 
  //iniciar pero también es undefined

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'profile email'
      }).then(() => {
        const auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        if (!auth2) {
          reject(new Error('No se pudo obtener una instancia de auth2.'));
        } else {
          resolve(auth2);
        }
      }).catch( (error:any) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Mi problema es que al principio se abría el popup en Google Chrome. Ahora cada vez que presiono el botón, recuerda mi cuenta a ingresa correctamente.
El problema surge cuando ingreso desde otro navegador por primera vez, no se me abre ninguna página para colocar la contraseña de Google.

Intenta avanzar pero como no hay ningún usuario, emite la excepción.

Quiero buscar alguna forma para que siempre me pida la contraseña para ingresar.

Answer (score 0):

Adapté la función `loginWithGoogle()`
Para que se abra siempre el popup

```
async loginWithGoogle() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
        gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            scope: 'profile email'
        }).then(() => {
            const auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            if (!auth2) {
                reject(new Error('No se pudo obtener una instancia de auth2.'));
            } else {
                auth2.signIn().then(() => {
                    // Popup opened successfully, user can sign in
                    const user = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
                    resolve(auth2);
                }).catch((error:any) => {
                    // Error opening popup
                    reject(error);
                });
            }
        }).catch((error:any) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
});
}
```